# List of files in a git push using git archive

Tags: git, githooks, git-push, git-commit

Is there a way to get only those files that are in a `git push`, onto a separate folder, using `git archive`?

I tried the below solution

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip ${commitid}
```

but I can get the entire repository content.

I am basically looking for files that are being committed and pushed at the server side(pre-receive).

Comment: Please don't alter radically your question, ask another question if you have a new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command prepares an archive of all the files modified by the commit specified :

```
$ git diff-tree -z --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-id> | xargs -0 git archive -o list.zip HEAD:
```

Comment: Note that if the tree contains filenames with embedded whitespace, xargs will behave badly.  Easy workaround if your xargs has `-0` is to add `-z` to `git diff-tree` and `-0` to `xargs`.  (Also—I haven't tested this—what happens if the list is long enough to cause xargs to run `git archive` multiple times?)

Comment: @torek Both very astute observations. Updated the first fix as suggested.

Comment: @torek A potential workaround for the second issue would be to override the back-end command to append to existing archives. For example, the following command configures the backed tar command into append mode (-r) `git config tar.tar.gz.command "tar -cvrzf"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.. Was driving and couldnt reply asap.. Will try out the solution and will let you know.. kudos.. :)

Comment: I am running into one issue here, i see that the files with spaces in them are not getting archived. I get an error when i do a git push. I tried different ways but not able to get it to work, any suggestions git experts? :)

Comment: Files with names containing spaces are being properly archived with the `-z` and `-0` flags added to `git diff-tree` and `xargs` correspondingly. Tested using git v1.8.1.2.

Comment: my version of git is 1.7.1.. And the arguments -z and -0 are not helping.. Is there an alternative solution, cos cant upgrade git anytime as of now..

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error and how to reproduce it?

Comment: I just create a new file with space in its name and when i use the command 
  git diff-tree -z --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-id> | xargs -0 git archive -o list.zip HEAD:  

i get the below error

  remote: fatal: path not found: WALL E.txt
remote:   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
remote:   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
remote:   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
remote:   the last disk(s) of this archive.  

the filename in the above example is WALL E.txt

Comment: The same cmds work perfectly for me. git v1.8.2. xargs(GNU findutils) v4.4.2. Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: so you are saying i need to upgrade git? :(

Comment: I am not entirely sure that the older version is an issue. Upgrading is easy as described in this [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/279175) and several others. Even [building **git** from source is simple](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source). In the event that upgrading **git** does NOT fix your issue, maybe you can post another question with the exact commands to describe the exact steps you are performing. It could be that we are missing something silly here... :)

Comment: Have posted a new question.. Thanks greatly for your support